# How do I search for a comment tag inside mp3 on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search, mp3, tags

How can I search for mp3 files that have the phrase "good" Inside the comment tag.

I tried to search for it in the Windows 7 search bar. I typed comment:"good" and it give me bad results. I want just the files that has "good" inside the comment tag of the mp3 file.

how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[**TagScanner**](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/index.htm) can do this easily:

[image]

Version 5.1.555 has added support for Windows 7. TagScanner is freeware.

Answer (score 2):

[Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) has a search function. The basic search, which includes comments, is available in the free version.

[image]

[image]