# How do I search for a comment tag inside mp3 on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I search for a comment tag inside mp3 on windows 7 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/111001/how-do-i-search-for-a-comment-tag-inside-mp3-on-windows-7)

hello

i want to search for mp3 files that have the phrase

"good"  Inside the comment tag.

i try to search for it in win7 search bar.
i typed
comment:"good"

and it give me bad results. 
i want just the files that has "good" inside the comment tag of the mp3 file.

how can i accomplish that ? thank you

Comment: i try also
comment:"good"

and it didnt work.

Comment: This seams like a question for http://superuser.com/ unless you are creating a program to do this.

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: Seriously, try to use some correct spelling. You are making it hard for users to follow what you mean...

Comment: Not everybody's first language is English. Please be understanding to people who can barely write it. :) We try.

Comment: Now a duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/111001/how-do-i-search-for-a-comment-tag-inside-mp3-on-windows-7